# Cookie managment in the blackberry mobile application

Tags: blackberry

I have to implement the remember me functionality on my blackberry application so that to remember the user's login credentials for the next login. Could any one please guide me on this and tell me how can I accomplish this functionality and how to use cookie for this? I am developing my application in blackberry 5.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's really an application and not a website, just save your login token (that you get back from your web service) to the persistent store.